# C# regex capture gets two results instead of one

Tags: c#, regex

I want to check whether an URL matches a pattern like: `http://the.site.com/some/path/1234567` and simultaneously extract the last number from it.

If I do this so:

```
Match m = Regex.Match(url, "^http://the.site.com/some/path/(?<picid>.*?)$");
if (m.Success)
{
    log(string.Format("New download. Id={0}", m.Groups["picid"].Value));
}
```

it returns 2 groups. One contains `http://the.site.com/some/path/1234567`, the other `1234567`. How to change the regex to get only one capture - the number?

Comment: The first group is always the entire match; you can't change that. Just use the second by specifying an index.

Comment: @acheong87: you are right, only the second group has a desired capture name. I've overlooked that in a hurry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the regex flag [RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx)

Usage :

```
Regex.Match(url, "^http://the.site.com/some/path/(?<picid>.*?)$", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
```

Comment: English version of that reference link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx

Answer (score 0):

By your example you need to check if the string match and get the last digit from the string in your example is 7 do this:

```
            Match m = Regex.Match(url, @"^http://the.site.com/some/path/\d+$");
            if (m.Success)
            {
                int y = int.Parse(m.Value[m.Value.Length - 1].ToString());
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Following Regex should capture only the number...

```
(?<=http://the.site.com/some/path/)(?<picid>.*?)$
```